# how can I show in a ngFor all the keys and values of a simple json?

Tags: angular

basically I have a json like (it's an example, my real json has n fields, and it can be dynamic):

```
data=
[
  {
    "name":"paul",
    "age":23,
    "gender":"male"
  },
  {
    "name":"adrian",
    "age":20,
    "gender":"male"
  },    
  {
    "name":"yorsy",
    "age":26,
    "gender":"male"
  }
]
```

I would like the output(first position):

```
key: name, value: paul
key: age, value:23
key: gender: value:male
```

how can I do it? I have an error because angular iterates over an array.

```
//in this case, I want show the first position of the data
<div *ngFor="let item of data[0]; let i=index">
  key: {{item}}, value: {{item[i]}}
</div>
```

this is my code:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j2rpdq

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Angular (v6.1.0 or grater), you can use `keyvalue` pipe from the common module of Angular package, like below -

```
<div *ngFor="let item of data[0] | keyvalue">
    Key: <b>{{item.key}}</b> and Value: <b>{{item.value}}</b>
</div>
```